# How to fetch user information from AWS Cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**Problem statement**: Getting `NotAuthorizedException` while performing `get_user` using `Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client`

**Tech Stack**: Angular, Ruby, AWS SDK of Ruby, Lambda Functions, Cognito User pool with hosted UI

**Cognito CSV Headers**:
`["name", "given_name", "family_name", "middle_name", "nickname", "preferred_username", "profile", "picture", "website", "email", "email_verified", "gender", "birthdate", "zoneinfo", "locale", "phone_number", "phone_number_verified", "address", "updated_at", "custom:pincode", "cognito:mfa_enabled", "cognito:username"]`

**Approach**:
In my Angular code I am using link like below to authorise user.
`https://auth1.blah.in/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback`

- Using above link I am able to sign up
- Perform login

and getting redirected to my callback URL with param code.

Now I am using this code to receive user information using ruby code like below.

```rb
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider'


client =  Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  region: "us-east-1"
)


resp = client.get_user({
  access_token: "yyyyyyyy-8d77-zzzz-92e1-xxxxxxx", 
})
```

getting below response from above code

```
`call': Invalid Access Token (Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::NotAuthorizedException)
```

While searching for solution, I came across few links which mentioned, I will have to use scope in my authorise URL, so users will have access to call API's

After adding scope and other parameters, below is what my URL looks like.

`https://auth1.blah.in/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback&state=STATE&scope=phone+openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&identity_provider=COGNITO`

To this Cognito hosted UI doesn't open and redirects with error like below.

`http://localhost:4200/callback?error_description=invalid_scope&state=STATE&error=invalid_request`

**Summary:**

1. Is this the right approach? please guide if not, I am new to Cognito.
2. What is Scope in authorise link?

Appreciate the help.

---

**Update (17-Jul-2023)**

After generating code, using same code we need to generate token.
ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

used below code to generate `access_token`.

```rb
curl --request POST  --location 'https://auth1.blah.in/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic longgggggblahblahblah==' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'code=xxxxxxxx-a80e-yyyyyy-a5f6-zzzzzzzz' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback'
```

which gives response with access_token, refresh_token etc

Was under impression, now all the struggle ends :D

used below code to finally fetch the userInfo

```rb
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider'


client =  Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  region: "us-east-1"
)


resp = client.get_user({
  access_token: "longgggstring............"
})
```

and below response is what I received

`NotAuthorizedException (Access Token does not have required scopes)`

If someone can throw some light on this scope part, it will be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some work around this issue I have been facing.

**Solution**

1. Generate URL from Angular app, once login callback gets code
2. Backend call, send code receive access token, refresh token
3. one more backend call, decode access token, and use `admin_get_user` to get user's details.

**Step 1: Generate URL from Angular**
As mentioned in my question, will be using same method to generate URL. to redirect users to hosted UI of Cognito

```
https://auth1.blah.in/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback
```

**Step 2: backend call to receive access, refresh token**
used below Ruby code in AWS Lambda to generate tokens, please node code is only valid for 1 time use and 5 minutes.

```rb
require "uri"
require "net/http"
require "base64"


def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    url = URI(ENV['cognito_url'])

    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64(ENV['client_id'] + ":" + ENV['client_secret'])
    request.body = "grant_type=authorization_code"
    request.body += "&code="+event['code']
    request.body += "&redirect_uri=" + ENV['redirect_uri']
    
    response = https.request(request)
    JSON.parse(response.read_body) 
    # { statusCode: 200, body: response.read_body }
end
```

**Step 3: Get user's details**
Used below python code, this one is not written by me, its easily available on net.
ref: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt/decode-verify-jwt.py

```py
# Copyright 2017-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file
# except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at
#
#     http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
#
# or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS"
# BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

import os
import json
import time
import urllib.request
from jose import jwk, jwt
from jose.utils import base64url_decode

region = os.environ.get('region')
userpool_id = os.environ.get('userpool_id')
app_client_id = os.environ.get('app_client_id')

keys_url = 'https://cognito-idp.{}.amazonaws.com/{}/.well-known/jwks.json'.format(region, userpool_id)
# instead of re-downloading the public keys every time
# we download them only on cold start
# https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/
with urllib.request.urlopen(keys_url) as f:
  response = f.read()
keys = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))['keys']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    token = event['token']
    # get the kid from the headers prior to verification
    headers = jwt.get_unverified_headers(token)
    kid = headers['kid']
    # search for the kid in the downloaded public keys
    key_index = -1
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        if kid == keys[i]['kid']:
            key_index = i
            break
    if key_index == -1:
        print('Public key not found in jwks.json')
        return False
    # construct the public key
    public_key = jwk.construct(keys[key_index])
    # get the last two sections of the token,
    # message and signature (encoded in base64)
    message, encoded_signature = str(token).rsplit('.', 1)
    # decode the signature
    decoded_signature = base64url_decode(encoded_signature.encode('utf-8'))
    # verify the signature
    if not public_key.verify(message.encode("utf8"), decoded_signature):
        print('Signature verification failed')
        return False
    print('Signature successfully verified')
    # since we passed the verification, we can now safely
    # use the unverified claims
    claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)
    print(claims)
    # additionally we can verify the token expiration
    if time.time() > claims['exp']:
        print('Token is expired')
        return False
    # and the Audience  (use claims['client_id'] if verifying an access token)
    if claims['client_id'] != app_client_id:
        print('Token was not issued for this audience')
        return False
    # now we can use the claims
    # print(claims)
    return claims['username']
        
# the following is useful to make this script executable in both
# AWS Lambda and any other local environments
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for testing locally you can enter the JWT ID Token here
    event = {'token': ''}
    lambda_handler(event, None)
```

Above code returns with user_id, which can be further used to receive all the details of user from Cognito

```rb
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider'

client =  Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(
  region: ENV['region']
)

resp = client.admin_get_user({
  user_pool_id: ENV['user_pool_id'], # required
  username: event['code'], # required
})
```